# Integral $I=\int_0^1 \frac{\log x \log (1+x) \log(1-x) \log(1+x^2)\log(1-x^2)}{x^{3/2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, summation

Hi I am trying to integrate and obtain a closed form result for
$$
I:=\int_0^1 \frac{\log x \log (1+x) \log(1-x) \log(1+x^2)\log(1-x^2)}{x^{3/2}}dx.
$$
Here is what I tried (but I do not think this is a smart way because of all the sums): writing
$$
I=\int_0^1 \frac{dx\log x}{x^{3/2}} \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{ (-1)^{n}x^n}{n}\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{x^m}{m}\sum_{l=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^lx^{2l}}{l}\sum_{p=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^p(-x^2)^{p}}{p}.
$$
Now we can write
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{ (-1)^{n}}{n}\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{m}\sum_{l=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^l}{l}\sum_{p=1}^\infty \frac{1}{p} \int_0^1  x^{n+m+2l+2p-3/2}\log x \, dx. 
$$  We can simplify this as
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ (-1)^{n}}{n}v\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{m}\sum_{l=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^l}{l}\sum_{p=1}^\infty \frac{1}{p}\left[ \frac{-1}{\big(  n+m+2l+2p -\frac{1}{2}  \big)^2}\right].
$$
I am stuck as to what to do From here,  note above I used
$$
-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}=\log(1-x),\quad \log(1+x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}x^n}{n},\quad \int_0^1 x^n \log x \, dx =\frac{-1}{(n+1)^2}.
$$

Comment: Hoho, where did you get this badboy?

Comment: @Nameless hoho! this one comes from the land of Saturn's moons.  They call them the standard Log Integrals.

Comment: Approximation: $-0.061442$

Comment: @qwr I got -0.066983824515258197496827371 ... in Mathematica 10 by setting `WorkingPrecision` 200, `PrecisionGoal` 200, and `AccuracyGoal` $\infty$. By the way, no match from [the two](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advancedCalc) inverse calculators [I tried](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html).